# How can I change Page Title periodically and switch the change on/off?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to change the title of my page periodically, i.e. add a (*) in front of the current page title and remove it after a couple of seconds. I want to turn this title change on and off in code.

I get and set the page title from:

```
    public static native void setPageTitle(String title) /*-{
    $doc.title = title;
    }-*/;


public static native String getPageTitle() /*-{
    return $doc.title;
}-*/;
```

But how should I write a function that will change the page title every 300 miliseconds while adding and removing a prefix?

What I tried was:

```
private void changePageTitle(final String prefix) {

    new Timer() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String pageTitle =getPageTitle();

            if (pageTitle.startsWith(prefix)) {
                    pageTitle = pageTitle.substring(prefix.length());
                }
                else {
                    pageTitle = pageTitle + prefix;
                }
            setPageTitle(pageTitle);

        }
        }
    }.schedule(300);
}
```

This does not work. And I do not know how to switch the process on and off?

The Effect should be like in Facebook. When a new message arrive and you are not on the Facebook browser tab, then the tab shows a notification which is blinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `schedule(300)` by `scheduleRepeating(300)`.

You should use just one instance of Timer or save the last timer to cancel it before creating a new one.

BTW: you dont need to write any JSNI to access the window title, just use `Window.getTitle()` and `Window.setTitle(String)`

EDITED:

This should work:

```
// create just an instance of the timer
final MyUpdateTitleTimer mytimer = new MyUpdateTitleTimer();
// To Start the updater
mytimer.setPrefix("> ");
// To Stop set the prefix to null
mytimer.setPrefix(null);


class MyUpdateTitleTimer extends Timer {
  private String prefix;
  private String title;
  private boolean b;

  public void run() {
    String s = (b = !b) ? prefix + title : title;
    Window.setTitle(s);
  }

  public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
    if (title != null) {
      Window.setTitle(title);
    }
    this.prefix = prefix;
    if (prefix == null) {
      cancel();
    } else {
      title = Window.getTitle();
      scheduleRepeating(300);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code on how I access the Timer to stop and start the timer?

Comment: Actually I dont understand what effect you want in the tittle, could you explain a bit better?

Comment: The Effect should be like in Facebook. When a new message arrive and you are not on the Facebook browser  tab, then the tab shows a notification which is blinking.

Comment: how can I access the timer such that I can start and stop it and start it with different prefix Strings?

Comment: Of course just create your own implementation of timer extending it, updated my respnse.